# Bootstrap Some of the glyphicons do not work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add an arrow pointing down. So I've tried several css code like this one from the **Bootstrap** own site, but I don't see anything.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

- glyphicon-menu-down
- glyphicon-triangle-bottom
- glyphicon-arrow-down

Meanwhile, some other glyphicons, such as **glyphicon-search**, are working just fine.

Any reason some of the icons do not work?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Browser? Version?

Comment: This is the link to the Bootstrap page http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons , so I assume that it's the latest version

Comment: I mean the browser you're testing with (Chrome, Firefox, IE?. What version of browser do you use?

Comment: Chrome: Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit), Edge: 25.10586.672.0, EdgeHTML: 15.10586

Answer (score 0):

Clean the cache of the browser, then refresh the page. Depending on which browser you are using, you can configure cache and offline data in the options.